# Handling nested dependencies in C++

Tags: c++, dependencies, microcontroller, mplab

I am new to programming in C++, my background is in the frontend space with react.

I've started a side project with micro-controllers and I'm having some problems with understanding how handling dependencies work with C++. In react, we would just use a package manager such as Npm or Yarn.

My problem is my `main.c` file includes `#include <NewSoftSerial.h>` which I have externally downloaded and manually added to my project folder from https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_NewSoftSerial.html.

However `newSoftSerial` itself has it's own set of `#includes<PACKAGE_NAME>' which are not in my project folder and therefore my build does not compile successfully.

Is it expected that developers have to manually hunt for all nested dependencies and manually add them? is there an easier way?

Comment: There is no such thing like C/C++. C and C++ are two different languages. You shouldn't learn both at the same time. _"Is it expected that developers have to manually hunt for all nested dependencies and manually add them? is there an easier way?"_ You probably know npm and yarn. In the C world there are package managers like [vcpkg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg) or [Conan](https://conan.io/). Depending on your OS there are also package managers for your system like brew (Mac), apt (Ubuntu), pacman (Arch Linux), dnf (CentOS / RHEL / Fedora), ...

Comment: What file does it failed to find?

Comment: There are as many answers to this question as there are stars in the sky.

In general your operating system's package manager is not going to help you when you are writing code for a microcontroller.

The simplest answer is yes, you have to identify yourself all the dependencies and make them available somehow.  Personally i prefer to do this using git submodules: 
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: @appleapple `Print.h`

Comment: @TomV I thought that might be the case, I'll take a look at git sub modules

Comment: @ThomasSablik C and C++ are absolutely identical in the context of this question, which is how do I make include headers available.  This is a question about getting files onto the C- pre-processor include path. C and C++ use the pre-processor in exactly the same way.

Comment: `Print.h` is part of Arduino core. It should be found if the build env is correct.

Comment: @TomV Obviously it's not. `Print.h` is part of Arduino and Arduino is C++, not C. `Print.h` contains classes. The answers are probably similar for both languages but OP has the problem of using C++ libraries in a C project (main.c) therefore I think it's helpful to mention that C and C++ are two different languages and it's not trivial to use C++ headers in a C project.

Comment: `NewSoftSerial.h` is also a C++ header. `Serial.begin(9600)` can't be compiled with a C compiler. You should rename `main.c` to `main.cpp` to avoid problems. Some compilers choose libraries and settings by file extension and this project is C++.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to embedded development. Yes, that's how most external libraries get added. Not only do you have to find and add them, you get to read the README and follow integration instructions (if there are any; often you just have to figure it out on your own). Additionally, there are different popular non-compatible build systems (usually make and CMake) - if the dependency doesn't support the build system in your project or expects to use it differently than you do - well, sometimes it's better to find another library :). The really useful libraries consist of a single .c and .h file without third party dependencies, which you just pull into your build system. Unsurprisingly embedded devs tend to write things from scratch to avoid the dependency horrors.

Then again, dependencies tend not to nest (at least for the good libraries). I'd be thinking long and hard before pulling in a library which has any third party dependencies.

In your case, specifically, the library (which, again, doesn't have any integration docs) expects an Arduino project whereas you seem to be using the Microchip's MPLab which is a completely different environment. There are really no good ways to solve this conflict other than create your project in Arduino (if your hardware is supported there); or find another library; or write the required functionality yourself.

Comment: The good thing about Arduino is it's just GCC with Makefiles and even beginners can analyze what's going on. It's pretty simple to convert an Arduino project to a C++/Makefile project.

Comment: Well, Arduino is good for beginners in many ways - if you can accept the limitations of it. As for converting an Arduino sketch to a Makefile project - that's actually something I've tried some 5 or 6 years ago and failed miserably. The Arduino libraries were hidden somewhere behind the scenes (undocumented, of course) and no matter what I tried, I couldn't find and link them.